# Persisting doctrine results with different values

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine, symfony4

I have some complex thing that I want to accomplish with one method.

In my Symfony project I am checking if the current datetime field is X days into the past.
I am persisting boolean field to **true** on every table row where it is.  So createdDate is *less-than* X days.

This part works as it should.

What I am trying to do is to the method goes both ways.

I want it also that if  createdDate is *greater-than* X days. Also, to persist boolean field to **false** on every table row where it is.

My code:

```
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->modify('-7 days');

    $users = $this->userRepo->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.createdDate < :date')
        ->setParameter(':date', $date)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->setExceeded(true);

        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $users;
```

Is there any possible way to do it and not in a separate method?

Like:

```
if() {

  ->andWhere('u.createdDate > :date')

   $user->setExceeded(false);
 }
```

Comment: 1) Two `where` conditions, with `or` 2) Make the check once more in the loop and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Well, that is the part I know. I wanted to add OR statement in doctrine, but how can I fit reverse persisting.  $user->setExceeded(false); ? @El_Vanja

Comment: Perform the check in the loop. Compare `$date` and `$user->getCreatedDate()` or whatever your getter is called (just make sure you create two date instances). Or, you could simply do another query and another loop within the same function, merging the results before returning.

Comment: Would you mind showing me quick example as I am still now sure how it can be done? @El_Vanja

Comment: `if ($user->getCreatedDate() < $date) { $user->setExceeded(true) } else { $user->setExceeded(false) }` combined with `orWhere` that has your other greater-than condition.

Comment: It seems to me like double work. Then doctrine returns all results like with findAll() than and again checking in if statement. @El_Vanja

Comment: Well, then do `findAll` and filter them out in the loop. No way around a bunch of work if you want to update your entire set of entities.

Comment: Do you really need to store that information in your db? You cannot handle that in the application? E.g. as an additional method in your entity:
`public function isExceeded():bool { return $this->created < new DateTime('-7 days');}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->modify('-7 days');
$users = $this->userRepo->findAll();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->setExceeded($user->getCreatedDate() < $date);
}
$this->entityManager->flush();

return $users;
```